# Find the corresponding link in a list with matches

Tags: python

my list contains the link and the title of the movie for example, searching for the movie spartacus on a subtitle site gives me two results I'm looking for the link to Spartacus (1960) my code always gives me the second link if you say  /movie-5751.html

```
('xxxxxxx', ['<a href="/movie-2877.html">Spartacus (1960)</a>', '<a href="/movie- 5751.html">Spartacus (2004)</a>'])
hr= 1960
hrefxxx /movie-5751.html
yearxx 1960
href /movie-5751.html
```

.Spartacus (1960)
.Spartacus (2004)

```
import requests, re

year = '1960'  


def getSearchTitle(title, year=None): 
    url = "http://www.moviesubtitles.org/search.php"
    params = ({'q': title, 'submit': 'Search'})
    data = s.post(url,data=params,headers=HDR,verify=False,allow_redirects=True).text 
    #with open(LINKFILE, "a") as f: f.write(data)
    blocks = re.compile('(<a href="/movie.+?</a>)').findall(data)
    print(("xxxxxxx", blocks))    
    blocks.pop(0)
    list1 = []
    for block in blocks:
        regx = '''<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>'''
        try:
            matches = re.findall(regx, block)
            name = matches[0][1]
            href = matches[0][0]
            print("hr=", str(year))
            print("hrefxxx", href)
            print("yearxx", year)
            if year and str(year) in name:
              if name and str(year) in blocks:
                regx2 = '<a href="(.*?)">'+name+'</a>'
                match = re.findall(regx2, blocks)
                print("match", match)
            if "/movie" in href:
                print("href", href)
                return href
                href = 'http://www.moviesubtitles.org' + href
            if year and year == '':
              if "/movie" in href:
                  return href
            if not year:
              if "/movie" in href:
                  return href

        except:
            break
    return 'http://www.moviesubtitles.org' + href
```

Comment: `if year and str(year) in name:` doesn't do what you think it does, I think

Comment: How many sentences does your first paragraph have?

Comment: The `if year and year == '':` block will never be reached, unless `year` is a peculiar object that has something like `def __bool__(self): return True` and `def __eq__(self, other): return other == ''`.